# iOS Firebase crash, APMMeasurement fetchRemoteConfig

Tags: ios, firebase, crash

I use Firebase and I received this crash. The problem is could not represent this.
I found this question, but my logs are not totally the same.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4154

Please let me know what can be the reason for this case.
Thanks

```
0 apmpb_free_measurement_config_field + 4299283084
1 apmpb_free_measurement_config + 4299283424
2 -[APMPBMeasurementConfig initWithBuffer:] + 4299263180
3 __71-[APMMeasurement networkRemoteConfigFetchCompletionHandler:data:error:]_block_invoke + 4298973976
4 -[APMSqliteStore performTransactionWithError:block:] + 4299111252
5 -[APMDatabase performTransaction:] + 4298834420
6 -[APMMeasurement networkRemoteConfigFetchCompletionHandler:data:error:] + 4298973824
7 __35-[APMMeasurement fetchRemoteConfig]_block_invoke + 4298971836
```

Comment: The reason for the crash is that you have a coding error - probably having to do with `APMMeasurement`. Can you tell us where you received this crash? Did you try debugging your code by adding a breakpoint and stepping through it line by line until the error appears? Did you ensure your cocoapods and Firebase is up-to-date?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I can't repro it. Only one of the users actually crashing on this. OS :  iOS 13.1.3. Device : iphone XR.